# How to yield all values returned by nested iterator?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, yield

I created a simple in-depth tree scan for JSON (only lists and values, without objects):

```
def depth(x):
    for e in x:
        if type(e) == list:
            for s in depth(e):
                yield s
        else:
            yield(e)
```

Construction

```
for s in depth(e):
    yield s
```

works fine, but I don't like it.

Is any *nice* way to yield everything yielded by calling function, without cycles?

Comment: I would avoid the special-casing - always deal with a sequence or never do - if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.3 or higher you can use [`yield from depth(e)`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).  In earlier versions of Python you must write out the nested loop as you have done.